# Cannot Load image without absolute path

Tags: java, image, swing, ioexception

I am trying to display an image in my swing application and cannot seem to do so without absolute file addressing. This is a problem because I need to be able to give this program to others to use, and cannot have it addressed just to my computer. The code that loads the image is below:

```
public void loadImage(){
    try{
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("mock logo 128x128.png"));
        logoImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Logo not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am certain that the file is in the src folder, so I know that is not the problem. if I setup the code like this:

```
public void loadImage(){
    try{
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Dan\\Documents\\EXSoft\\ExSoft Workspace\\Septic Calculator Alpha\\src\\mock logo 128x128.png"));
        logoImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Logo not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly. But as previously stated, this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: From my understanding, when using Eclipse, you should store your resources in the resources directory at the same level as your src directory.  Eclipse will automatically include this within it's build process.  You can then access the resources as an embedded resource. Don't use Eclipse so I'm scratchy on the details, but that's my understanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the file in the src folder, therefore its packaged as part of your app. Its not outside your app binary. therefore you must use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream`.

Example:

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mock logo 128x128.png"));
```